# When I attempt to match a double value from a json array it fails with the expected value having angle brackets around it. What does this mean?

Tags: rest-assured-jsonpath

Using RestAssured I attempt to check the following piece of JSON:

```
    {
        "id": "abc1",
        "commonName": "Plane",
        "location": [
            1.1,
            1.1
        ]
    }
```

with the following piece of java code:

```java
    double[] location = new double[]{1.1,1.1};
    given()
    .when()
        .get("tree/abc1/")
    .then()
        .assertThat()
        .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
        .body("location[0]", is((location[0])));
```

The last assertion fails with the following error

```
    java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
    JSON path location[0] doesn't match.
    Expected: is <1.1>
      Actual: 1.1
```

What do the angle brackets around the expected value indicate and how can I get the assertion to succeed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default type for JSON numbers is float when using rest assured. I presume the angle brackets are indicating a type mismatch.

The solution is to set the rest assured configuration in the given block to specify the number type.

```java
double[] location = new double[]{1.1,1.1};
given()
    .config(RestAssured.config().jsonConfig(jsonConfig().numberReturnType(JsonPathConfig.NumberReturnType.DOUBLE)))
.when()
    .get("tree/abc1/")
.then()
    .assertThat()
    .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
    .body("location[0]", is(location[0]));
```

Comment: Or `body("location[0]", equalTo(location[0]))` or `body("location[0]", is((float)location[0]))`

Comment: No, angle brackets do NOT indicate a _type_ mismatch. They simply enclose the actual and expected value. `assertThat(1, is(2))` is not a type mismatch (two ints) and still renders the brackets.

Comment: See [`org.hamcrest.BaseDescription`](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/BaseDescription.java) for how the values are rendered

Answer (score 0):

**Returning floats and doubles as BigDecimal**

> instead of having two different type of configuration, Convert all
>   floats and doubles into BigDecimal and then Compare then in the
>   hamcrest Matcher

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)