# Hamcrest(Java) errors

Tags: java, testing, rest-assured, hamcrest

I'm using REST Assured with Hamcrest matchers in my tests:

```java
given()
    //...
    .assertThat()
    .body("id", arrayContaining(job1.getId(), job2.getId()))
    .statusCode(200);
```

After running them I get the following error:

```
JSON path id doesn't match.
Expected: is [<70a1deec-ce17-4064-8037-5e546d3ed329>, <7ccd5ad0-7425-4df5-be64-bb8584da5d96>]
  Actual: <[70a1deec-ce17-4064-8037-5e546d3ed329, 7ccd5ad0-7425-4df5-be64-bb8584da5d96]>
```

The response has following format:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "some UUID 1"
        "other_properties": ...
    },
    {
        "id": "some UUID 1"
        "other_properties": ...
    }
]
```

My question is what triangle brackets mean? And which matcher is better to use. I know I probably just googled it wrong, but I've spent few days by googling and reading documentation and examining code on github. Yet still haven't find explanation about errors format. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the selector, but your matcher.
`arrayContaining` can only match against *arrays*, while `contains` can match against any kind of *`Iterable`*.

[`arrayContaining`](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#arrayContaining-E...-):

> `public static <E> Matcher<E[]> arrayContaining(E... items)`
>
> Creates a matcher for arrays that matches when each item in the examined array is logically equal to the corresponding item in the specified items. For a positive match, the examined array must be of the same length as the number of specified items. For example:
>
> `assertThat(new String[]{"foo", "bar"}, arrayContaining("foo", "bar"))`

[`contains`](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains-E...-):

> `public static <E> Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends E>> contains(E... items)`
>
> Creates a matcher for Iterables that matches when a single pass over the examined `Iterable` yields a series of items, each logically equal to the corresponding item in the specified items. For a positive match, the examined iterable must be of the same length as the number of specified items. For example:
>
> `assertThat(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), contains("foo", "bar"))`

So change your assertion to `.body("id", contains(job1.getId(), job2.getId()))` and your test should succeed.

Comment: body method doens't seem to support such a format: ```SampleIT.test_getAllJobsAndCountWithStatusCode200:147 » IllegalArgument Invalid JSON expression: Script1.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: '[' @ line 1, column 28. $[*].id```

Comment: @Some_Person did you try `*.id`? It that doesn't work, try `$.[*].id`

Comment: REST Assured supports only GPath notation, and it doen't have specific symbol for root. As I understood If I want to search for ```id``` everywhere i just need to type ```id```: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61343406/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-invalid-json-expression-script1-groovy-1. The problem still is with the wrong matcher I am using (I assume)

Comment: @Some_Person had a look at the docs again. I think the problem is the `arrayContaining` matcher, which should be `hasItems` instead. I have updated my answer. Please verify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped. And answering my other question, <> mean type mismatch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57806720/when-i-attempt-to-match-a-double-value-from-a-json-array-it-fails-with-the-expec

Comment: @Some_Person no, `<…>` doesn't mean "type mismatch". `<…>` wrap the expected value. `arrayContaining` will match each value in the array with a separate matcher instance, that's why there are multiple angle brackets. They simply enclose the actual and expected values. `assertThat(1, is(2))` is NOT a type mismatch and still renders the brackets. ([source](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/collection/ArrayMatching.java#L148))